# How prevent `MatListOption` to be checked/unchecked?

Tags: angular, list, angular-material, readonly

**Setup:**

Angular Material 8.1.4.

Using:

[MatSelectionList](https://material.angular.io/components/list/api#MatSelectionList) and
[MatListOption](https://material.angular.io/components/list/api#MatListOption)

**Issue:**

I need to show several previously selected items that won't be able to be checked/unchecked by the user, so they will behave as if they were `readonly`.

The issue arises to the fact that [MatListOption](https://material.angular.io/components/list/api#MatListOption) doesn't have support for a `readonly` attribute, which effectively could solved my issue.

Setting `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"` doesn't prevent it to be clicked neither.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

pd. For reference, I did just created a feat-issue at https://github.com/angular/components/issues/17141

ppd. I did tested using `disabled` but that prevent the items to be added to the final list, which is not the intended behavior.

Comment: I still don't get it you can programmatically select elements to select's value even though they are disabled that serves as checked and user can't check or uncheck them.

Comment: I selected Sausage and Tomato in here tomato is disabled mat option so user can't check uncheck but the programmer can . isn't this what you want? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-69ivya

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That checks the item but the result is the same, as they are disabled, they do not make it to `form.value`. I'm using `select=true` to achieve the same effect in a declarative way.

Comment: What I'm looking after is a way to have them checked always, so the user cannot uncheck them, but that those items make it in to a `form.value` call.

Comment: Also, take into account that I'm not using `mat-select` here, but `mat-selection-list` and `mat-list-option`, which generates a checkboxes list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding an extra `(selectionChange)="selectedChanged($event)"` event, defined as:

```
selectedChanged($event: MatSelectionListChange) {
    if ($event.option.value.isChecked) {
      $event.option.selected = true;
    }
  }
```

`isChecked` here is the business filter I'm using to discriminate the selected options, by issuing `$event.option.selected = true;` the item remains selected, which was the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can prevent mat option being checked/unchecked if the condition is matched.

```
<mat-selection-list (selectionChange)="onChange($event)" >
    <mat-list-option  *ngFor="let data of dataList" [value]="data" >
        <h3>{{data}}</h3>
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>

onChange(event: any) {
    if(condition === false){
        event.option.selected = false;
    }
}
```